# Using st_buffer to generate buffer away from edge of polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-analyst

I am trying to find which bike paths come into an area no closer than 500m but no further than 700m of Melbourne. I believe I will use an `st_buffer` to create a buffer around Melbourne (I  have a melbourne polygon) and see what bike paths (lines) are contained within. However I am not sure how to create a buffer with these requirements.

Comment: Better use `ST_DWithin(geom1, geom2, 700) AND ST_Distance(geom1, geom2) > 500`; make sure you are using a proper projection, or a cast to `GEOGRAPHY`. An index on your bike route geometries (either on the column, or the cast) boosts performance significantly .

Answer (score 4):

This may guide you as an example:

```sql
SELECT ( ST_TRANSFORM(
  ST_SYMDIFFERENCE(
    ST_BUFFER(
      ST_TRANSFORM(
        ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(
          'POLYGON((
            144.94927 -37.80903,
            144.94227 -37.80203, 
            144.93727 -37.80203,
            144.94927 -37.80903 ))', 4326
        ),
        8059
      ),
      400
    ),
    ST_BUFFER(
      ST_TRANSFORM(
        ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(
          'POLYGON((
            144.94927 -37.80903,
            144.94227 -37.80203, 
            144.93727 -37.80203,
            144.94927 -37.80903 ))', 4326
        ),
        8059
      ),
      700
    )
  ),
  4326
  )
);
```

[image: Result]

The main idea being using [`ST_SymDifference`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SymDifference.html) to compute the symmetrical difference between two buffers, the second one being the largest.

You can avoid re-projecting to WGS84 but this was needed by pgAdmin to actually display the map. Also double check that your SRID matches your data.